# jQuery: IE9 not properly showing box-shadow on dynamically generated content via addClass()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, addclass

I have a page where I dynamically add controls and content to a div.  Later when doing validation, I parse through all the controls and use .addClass() to add a CSS class containing box-shadow to change the style.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE9 (I haven't tried IE10+ - don't have it in our environment at the moment.)

What is strange is I haven't been able to pin-point the exact reason and I'm getting a discrepancy between my environment and jsfiddle that I can't pin-point.  It acts exactly the same in jsfiddle, except when the css class has another entry like border-width.  In that case the box-shadow magically works.  This is different from my environment in that box-shadow doesn't show up for dynamic content in IE9 no matter what I do or how the CSS class looks.

I know addClass() works because when I inspect elements via F12 in IE9, I see the class attatched to the element.  Also, in my environment if my added class has something like a border, it works in IE9.  Just not the box-shadow, ever.

```js
addInput = function() {
    var myHtml = '<input type="text" style="width:100px;margin-top:5px;" class="myClass"></input><br />';
    $("#myDiv").append(myHtml);
}

styleInputs = function(style) {
    $(".myClass").addClass(style);
}

removeStyles = function() {
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myStyle1");
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myStyle2");
}
```

```css
.myStyle1 {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #A00;
}

.myStyle2 {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #A00;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" value="Add Input"/>
<input type="button" onclick="styleInputs('myStyle1')" value="Style Inputs 1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="styleInputs('myStyle2')" value="Style Inputs 2"/>
<input type="button" onclick="removeStyles()" value="Remove Styles"/><br />
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8fL24ko/6/

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding !imporant to the end of the class properties?

Comment: That didn't fix it but it led me to find `border-collapse: separate;` which made it work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
addInput = function() {
    var myHtml = '<input type="text" style="width:100px;margin-top:5px;" class="myClass"></input><br />';
    $("#myDiv").append(myHtml);
}

styleInputs = function(style) {
    $(".myClass").addClass(style);
}

removeStyles = function() {
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myStyle1");
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myStyle2");
}
```

```css
.myStyle1 {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #A00 !important;
}

.myStyle2 {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #A00 !important;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" value="Add Input"/>
<input type="button" onclick="styleInputs('myStyle1')" value="Style Inputs 1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="styleInputs('myStyle2')" value="Style Inputs 2"/>
<input type="button" onclick="removeStyles()" value="Remove Styles"/><br />
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't do it.  IE9 still doesn't display the box-shadow